# Render a SharePoint 2013 list view on a remote web page

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I'm developing a SharePoint 2013 **provider hosted app**.
It has a remote web and an aspx page [REMOTE WEB ASPX PAGE].

I would like to display a view of a list from the host web on the [REMOTE WEB ASPX PAGE].
I mean not just query list data via CSOM and display it in aspx ListView control but have:

- look and feel like it is on the host web
- paging/sorting functionality
- [optionally] standard ribbon/ECB menu

I understand that I could create all of this by myself from scratch but is there any **standard** way of how I could accomplish that?